# drawing and remove a path with animation

Tags: android, animation, path

I got some points from user Touch and store them in an array ,
I  draw lines (by quadTo method) between these points with Animation.
that's ok by using Value Generate Animators.

but the ask is how can I remove them with Animation?
means for example after draw lines between A and B and C points (start from A and ends in C) with Animation , how can I remove these lines after one second with Animation?(remove from start point A to end point C)

Am I missing any methods in APIs that behave for similar task I want?
or anybody can help me how can I implement it?
thanks for your attention , and sorry for my bad English:)

Comment: How are you currently animating the addition of points? Removal is basically the same, you would just need a some temporary values to animate from A (getting removed) to B

Comment: so how can I remove the Lines ? I couldn't find any method for that in APIs

Comment: There is no such method as removing a path fragment, but you can clear the whole path with reset(). What you may wish to do is keeping a list of all points. Then at any animation step  you remove the last point from the list, then do reaset() and quadTo() in a loop fall all remaining points. You need to keep a back buffer, so that the redrawing would not be noticeable.

Comment: That is a good idea.  Although i was thinking about this case too.  But,i wonder myself if it could be another way for it that would be better even.  Cause i need this for making a game application.  I saw it lately that in 2 different games when player touches the screen and drag it away it would be kind of shadow that fades with time spending itself (almost what i want)  i wonder myself if that would be kind of method in applications that i wasn't observed them